# Node.js Updating file stored on S3 using Streams

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, stream, node-streams, event-stream

What I want to do is read a file from S3 - update some information - upload it back, all using streams, without having to create a copy of the file on the server.
I used the event-streams library for parsing the file like this:(Updated with solution !)

```
let params = {
    Bucket: Bucket,
    Key: Key,
};
let rStream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
let updatedFile = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/updated-' + Key);

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let s = rStream
        .pipe(es.split())
        .pipe(es.mapSync(function(data) {
            if(!data) return;

            s.pause();
            let line = data.split(',');

            if(line[1]==='xyz'){
                line[1] = 'xyz11';
            }

            updatedFile.write(line.join(','));
            updatedFile.write('\n');

            s.resume();
        })
        .on('error', function(err) {
            reject(err);
        })
        .on('end', function() {
           updatedFile.end();

           //createReadStream from path of updatedFile
           //s3 upload file logic
           //delete tmp file logic
           resolve(true);
        }));
});
```

My problem is that when I return this stream back, its closed and has readable : false , so I cannot use it :

```
const updatedStream = fs.createReadStream(tmpfilePath); 
            params={
                Bucket: Bucket,
                Key: Key,
                Body: updatedStream
            };
await s3.upload(params)
  .on('httpUploadProgress', (progress) => {
       console.log('progress', progress)
  })
  .send();

try {
   fs.unlink(tmpfilePath, function (err) {
     if (err) throw err;
       console.log("Tmp File deleted successfully.");
      });
} catch(err) {
   console.log("Warning: Unable to delete the tmp file.", err);
}
```

Any thoughts? The event-stream closes the stream on end and that's why its readable:false when I pass it back.

How can I create a read stream, change the data and have the stream readable in order to pass it to the s3.upload function?

**SOLUTION**

In the end I managed to get this working.

I created a writeStream temp file in whom I write after each iteration. When the stream ends I close the writeStream to close my temporary file.

Then I upload it back to S3 (creating a readStream from the my temp file).

Once the upload is done I delete my temporary file.